# How to autodetect the file location in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filepath

I just wondered if there are any ways to let your program find a file you want to use by just giving the name without writing the whole search path like this.

```
Scanner betalningsservice = new Scanner(new File("/afs/nada.kth.se/home/i/u1vxrjgi/betalningsservice.txt"));
        String  line1             = betalningsservice.nextLine();
```

You can see that its a pretty long path and I would like the program to be able to detect the file "betalningsservice.txt" whereever the file is located in the computer (in case the file has been moved to somewhere else). Any tips guys? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Considering the search utilities built into OSs sometimes have a hard time finding files, I'd imagine that this wouldn't be an easy or efficient task...

Answer (score 1):

Since there's some debate about what exactly is wanted in this question, I'll post another answer.

If you're using Java 8, finding a file is made somewhat simpler by using the `Files.find` function. It has the advantage of being able to limit how deep the search goes, keeping search speed under control. Here's an example that sticks the Paths of all matching files into a List. If you find more than one matching file you can have the user choose the right one:

```
final String SEARCH_FILE = "betalningsservice.txt"; // the file you're looking for
final String SEARCH_ROOT = "/afs/nada.kth.se/home/i/"; // where to start the search (top folder)
final int SEARCH_DEPTH = 4; // how many nested subfolders to delve into
final List<Path> files = new LinkedList<>();
Files.find(Paths.get(SEARCH_ROOT), SEARCH_DEPTH, (p, a) -> p.endsWith(SEARCH_FILE))
        .forEach(e -> files.add(e));
```

It's debatable whether one big-ass statement that does all of the logic of the search is more readable or less readable, but that's Java 8 for you.

If you want to get advanced, you can also append `FileVisitOption`s to the `find` function's parameter list (for example, to follow symbolic links).

It's interesting to note that in Java 8, `Path` has generally replaced `File` as the way to represent files and folders, hence the List of Paths. Once you've selected the correct Path (we'll say it's in a variable called `path`), you can use it similarly to how you would use a File:

```
Scanner betalningsservice = new Scanner(path);
```

The rest is as before.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a *practical/reliable* way to just find the file anywhere on the computer.
You can, however, utilize relative file paths if you know your working directory. So if your working directory were `/afs/nada.kth.se/home/i/u1vxrjgi`, you could refer to the file just by `new File("betalningsservice.txt")`. Similarly, if your working diretory were `/afs/nada.kth.se/home/i`, you could refer to the file as `new File("u1vxrjgi/betalningsservice.txt")`.

Another option would be to read from the classpath. This can be accomplished by getting the classloader to [get a resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: *"There is not a way to just find the file anywhere on the computer"* yeah, there is,but I wouldn't recommend it ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - It may be possible (though not practical) to search through every available file system to find files with that name. It is not possible to guarantee it finds /that/ file. A file with a duplicate name would produce undesirable results.

Comment: Hence, I wouldn't recommend it ;)

Answer (score 0):

`File` can also create files using  a relative path. Just don't start the file name with a slash. For example, if you run the program from the folder "/afs/nada.kth.se/home/i/u1vxrjgi/", you can just use:

```
new File("betalningsservice.txt")
```

...and that will get you the file you want.

Comment: While true, this doesn't *quite* answer the question. Your proposed method would require OP to find the file first, which isn't always possible (e.g. execution on a different computer)

Comment: @user3580294: Yes, it does. Read the question again.

Comment: "I would like the program to be able to detect the file "betalningsservice.txt" whereever the file is located in the computer (in case the file has been moved to somewhere else). Any tips guys? :)". You never answer this part. And as I said, your method doesn't really satisfy the requirement that it is the *program* that does the searching, not the user.

Comment: @user3580294: it depends on how you interpret the question. You can detect the file in any location by running the program from that location. If the file is moved, change the script that runs the program to change the working directory.

Comment: But then it isn't the *program* doing the detection, it's the user.

Comment: The program is indeed detecting the file, since it's right there in the working directory. You're reading more into what he said then is necessarily there. While that **may** be what he wants, he never said the program must be able to search for the file. He just said the program must be able to support moving the file, and the name should be shorter.

Comment: I think you're taking the question too literally. If you want to pick apart the question, so be it. What about the "let your program find a file you want to use by just giving the name without writing the whole search path" part? You still have to write the whole search path at some point for your solution.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong; I'm just saying either way is a possible interpretation. You could be right, so I would suggest that you write an answer extolling the virtues of the `Paths`/`Files` stuff in Java 8, which will indeed (more) easily search for a file.

Comment: I still think you should at least address whether an arbitrary search across the file system is possible in your answer for completeness's sake. I'd rather not write such an answer, as it's fraught with efficiency and correctness issues that would make such an answer more an exercise in frustration than anything else.

Comment: @user3580294: I'm not going to try to answer every possible interpretation of questions. I would be here all day and my answers would be pages long. I picked an interpretation that seems to fit what he's looking for (but may not). That's why I suggested you write an answer to cover the bases. I wasn't being facetious. The file stuff in Java 8 is simple enough that you could likely read the documentation and create an answer yourself without too much effort.

Comment: I'm not saying you should, but in this case it doesn't have to be long at all, as in the other answer. I'd rather not write a a poor answer, both through lack of familiarity with the `FileVisitor` interface and introduction of complications.

Comment: .....Well, I certainly can't complain. Well done! Didn't expect it to be that easy; what I had in my mind was much worse.